# Why is the real projective space $P^n$ equal to both unit sphere $S^n$ and unit ball $B^n$ with identified antipodal points?

Tags: general-topology, projective-geometry, projective-space

I saw this in *Basic Topology* by M.A.Armstrong. It gives three descriptions of real n-dimensional  projective space $P^n$. Two of them are:

(a) Begin with the unit sphere $S^n$ in $E^{n+1}$ and identify its antipodal points.

(c) Begin with the unit ball $B^n$ and identify antipodal points of its boundary sphere.

I find it hard to imagine why these two descriptions lead to the same space.

Can you please help? Thank you.

Comment: (a) is the same as the upper hemisphere, where you identify antipodal points on the boundary $S^{n-1}$  - and that in turn is the same as (b)

Comment: I would say (c) gives you n-1 dimensional projective space, while (a) gives you n dimensional.

Comment: @GEdgar , that's not true. In (c), only the antipodal points of the **boundary sphere** are identified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start with (a).  Given $S^n$, first think about all points *not* on the equator (here, if $S^n = \{(x_1,...,x_{n+1})|$ $x_1^2 + ... + x_{n+1}^2 = 1\}$, then the equator is all the points with, say, $x_{n+1} = 0$).

When we identify these particular points, every point has a unique representative in the open "northern" (i.e., $x_{n+1} > 0$) hemisphere.  We still need to make identifications on the equatorial boundary of the closed northern hemisphere.

Thus, we can obtain $\mathbb{R}P^n$ by taking just the northern hemisphere of a sphere and identitifying some more points on the equator.  But the northern hemisphere is a (closed) n-ball, and the equator is the boundary of the n-ball.  Finishing up the identificatin on $S^n$ is simply a matter of identifying antipodal points on the equator, but the equator *is* the boundary of the n-ball, so the two constructions give the same space.